# Can anyone tell me why this Codeigniter session data function seems to work.. but returns false?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So this has been killing me for hours.

I have an ajax method that sets sessiondata when the user logs in.  I'm sending a few vars via jQuery, and then outputting a message (could have just as well been "true"/"false"), which I am alerting out when it gets back to $.post.

Problem is this.. I am getting the "false" returned, although things seem to work.  My session userdata **does** seem to be setting correctly.  I built a button that alerts it out on the page and it **is** being set.  I log out and confirm that all session data is cleared, and re-login and the session data sets correctly again.  But the "false"/"PROBLEM WITH SESSION DATA" message is the one that is coming back to jQuery and being alerted every time.

```
public function setUserSessionData(){
    $picture    = $this->input->post('picture', TRUE);
    $email      = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name', TRUE);
    $id         = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);

    ChromePhp::log($picture.$email.$first_name.$id);  // all values good

    $newData = array(
        'loggedInStatus' => 'TRUE',
        'picture'        => $picture,
        'first_name'     => $first_name,
        'id'             => $id,
        'email'          => $email
    );

            // userdata is setting correctly
    if($this->session->set_userdata($newData))
    {
        echo("Session data set"); 
    }
    else
    {
        echo("PROBLEM WITH SESSION DATA"); // this is the message that is outputting
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: Did you load the session library? `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: Yup.  It's in my autoload.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_userdata()` always returns `NULL`.

I don't know where you go the idea that `set_userdata()` should return anything. The [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) does not mention a return value and the [code itself](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L294) is documented as `@return void` and does not contain a `return` statement.

Comment: Well you are my hero.  I just thought that since it was assigning a value that it would return a true/false if the assignment worked.  I never thought to check otherwise.  Hallelujah.  Francis will make a fine name for my firstborn.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a key in that session array?

```
$newData = array(
    'loggedInStatus' => TRUE,

// ...

$this->session->set_userdata($newData);

if($this->session->userdata('loggedInStatus') === TRUE){ 
    echo("Session data set"); 
}else{
    echo("PROBLEM WITH SESSION DATA");
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, but I gave your way a shot (using email as the key as to avoid any truthy/falsy issues) and it still didn't work.  I set the data.. the email is set .. but it still returns my "fail message".  ACK!